# How can I speed up this regex in R?

Tags: regex, r, performance

I have a medium-sized factor of 1.5 million rows. The data is coordinates of the form `(15.500593489554, -98.593930203954)`.

I want to extract each coordinate, convert it to numeric, and have them in separate columns. The issue is that the code I have written takes so long that it eats all my ram (8 GB), R crashes, and my computer locks up. It stays at 99% physical memory usage even after R is restarted.

Here is the code I used to just extract the first coordinate from the factor:

```
library(stringr)
sapply(dat, function(x) as.numeric(str_match(x, "([.0-9]+),")[,2]))
```

Since this wasn't working, I decided to subset the data set and found that doing the command on 100 rows takes a few seconds. 1000 rows takes about 25 seconds. So even if I split the data into chunks, processed them separately, and put it back together it would take many hours.

Is there a better way to approach this issue? I couldn't figure out how to use my regex command with base R (`grep()`, `gsub()` etc.). Is `str_match()` just slower?

Here is a sample dataset the mimics the structure of my data:

```
dat <- factor(replicate(1500000, paste("(", runif(1, 0, 150), ", ", runif(1, -150, 0), ")", sep = "")))
```

And for reference, here is my regex for extracting the second coordinate of the pair:

```
as.numeric(str_match(x, "([-.0-9]+)\\)")[,2]))
```

Comment: You need to understand vectorization. All these loops are killing you. E.g., there is no reason to use `replicate` when creating your `dat` since `runif` is vectorized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the data on comma and strip out the first and last characters:

```
splits = strsplit(as.character(substr(dat,2,nchar(as.character(dat))-1)),",")
```

then turn that into a numeric matrix:

```
> xy = matrix(as.numeric(do.call(rbind,splits)),ncol=2) 
> dat[1:10]
 [1] (86.1234028358012, -6.26554019981995) (141.88499195734, -28.9505033288151) 
 [3] (48.9979103207588, -85.1732837269083) (22.5762162473984, -3.01207801094279)
 [5] (81.2530122930184, -26.4870180166326) (71.918728435412, -86.2695457180962) 
 [7] (1.14843629999086, -25.0385148217902) (90.2961491374299, -55.1420112024061)
 [9] (7.83875549677759, -58.2294602994807) (108.123476186302, -10.3448686539195)
1000 Levels: (0.0320718856528401, -10.3856220259331) ...
> head(xy)
          [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  86.12340  -6.265540
[2,] 141.88499 -28.950503
[3,]  48.99791 -85.173284
[4,]  22.57622  -3.012078
[5,]  81.25301 -26.487018
[6,]  71.91873 -86.269546
```

Practically instantaneous on a 100,000 length `dat` vector on my laptop.

Comment: You should set `fixed = TRUE`.

Comment: speeds the split phase up from 0.32s to 0.14s - matrix build phase takes 0.08s